# Was there an Amulet of Yendor in any of the D&D official, or 3rd party published material?

Tags: magic-items, dungeons-and-dragons, lore, history-of-gaming

Amulet of Yendor is a main artifact in many rogue-alike games, for example Rogue itself, NetHack and Pixel Dungeon families of computer / mobile games. It also appeared in many places as a homage or an easter egg. It is merely 6 years younger than D&D, and both coexisted in geeky fandom back then.

Have the Amulet of Yendor ever appeared in D&D material, in any D&D World, in any way that's not merely a homebrew? I do not particularly care about edition, as it might have appeared in something old, or recently due to nostalgia. If there are mentions of Amulet of Rodney, or Rodney the wizard who lost an amulet, I'll say it counts.

Comment: Note: I know that proving negative might be hard. I'm OK with this question staying unanswered if no mentions are found. Someone doing a big research would be a wonderful person, but I do not expect that ;) Rather, I just hope someone might simply remember it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Amulet of Yendor was mentioned in Dragon Magazine #112 (Aug 1986), in a review of *Rogue*, the original game for which all *roguelikes* are named.

However, the item itself does not appear in D&D, and it can be deduced that is is unlikely to have appeared in any official Dungeons & Dragons material.

- The Amulet of Yendor first appeared in the game *Rogue*, released (according to Wikipedia) in 1980. It is unlikely to have appeared in any D&D work earlier than this.
- The Amulet of Yendor does not appear in the index of *Encyclopedia Magica Volume 4*, which lists almost every single magic item in any TSR D&D or AD&D source or Dragon magazine prior to 1995.
- It does not appear in the DragonDex [List of Magic Items](https://www.aeolia.net/dragondex/magic-items.html), and therefore did not appear in any Dragon magazine article during its print run. The DragonDex also has no articles on the games Hack or NetHack.
- There are no hits for "Yendor" or "NetHack" at DriveThruRPG, ruling out most third-party publications.
- There are no hits for "Yendor" at [IMarvinTPA's database](https://imarvintpa.com/dndlive/index.php), which indexes most first-party D&D 3e books.
- There are no hits for "Yendor" in a Google search of wizards.com (although a DuckDuckGo search reveals a *Magic: the Gathering* player named for the Wizard of Yendor), ruling out D&D 3e web enhancements and official web articles.
- There are no hits for "Yendor" in the D&D 4e [Compendium](https://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/database.aspx), ruling out that entire edition.
- There are no hits for "Yendor" at the 5e repository D&D Beyond, ruling out that entire edition.
- A search of an unauthorized pirate site (which I won't link) reveals no hits for Yendor in a D&D context.

As a result, the only first-party sources that an Amulet of Yendor could possibly have appeared in were sourcebooks, Dungeon magazines, and Polyhedron magazines between 1995 and 2007. Even then, I believe it unlikely that they appeared in any of these, because:

- The original Amulet of Yendor is technically copyrighted material of the creators of the original *Rogue*. While *NetHack* technically violates copyright on some item names, it avoids problems because it is a free, non-commercial game. Wizards of the Coast took copyright issues seriously and would probably not want to risk it.
- It was uncommon for D&D books of the WotC era to throw in oblique references to pop culture or video games. The only exception is Dragon magazine's *Silicon Sorcery* article series, but none of these were done for *Rogue*, *Hack*, or *NetHack*.
- Dungeon magazine's [writer's guidelines](https://paizo.com/writersguidelines/dungeon_writer_guidelines.pdf) discouraged cliched adventures about recovering an artifact (like the Amulet of Yendor) or battling a deranged wizard (like the Wizard of Yendor), so an article featuring these probably did not appear in D&D 3e-era Dungeon magazine.
- The primary purpose of the Amulet of Yendor is a plot maguffin. It's not actually very interesting outside of the context of its game. While it does have other powers, its primary use is to sacrifice to a deity who needs it to gain ascendency above other gods, and that's not really a meaningful power outside of the story of the original games in which it appeared.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell from a simple Google search there isn't an Amulet of Yendor in any of the official published D&D material. In my experience you should be able to find any magic item (especially one that has a connection to an outside work) fairly easily. I also looked through my 5e material and was unable to find any reference to this particular item.

Also the only references to the amulet's other name that I can find are purely homebrew. I'm sorry I wasn't able to find it. My best suggestion if you want to use this item is to ask your DM to come up with something or to come up with something yourself. I've personally homebrewed quite a few magic items and I find that as long as you use common sense it's quite easy to make magic items that are balanced and fun for your part. One example of this is I created a magic rapier for a rogue that gave him an extra d6 damage  when activated and allowed a goddess to talk to him. he's enjoyed the extra flavor and he still uses the rapier in combat from time to time.

Comment: I haven't voted on your answer and I refrain from voting. There is a lot of material that was never uploaded to the internet, at least not openly, including all of the Forgotten Realms books, for example. Maybe there is nothing to be found. Maybe not.

Comment: @Mołot I think what Gwideon is getting at in mentioning a Google search is that at the very least we'll see game items mentioned in forum discussions, wikis, guides of various kinds, etc. Even relatively obscure game materials turn up some mention, and the Amulet of Yendor is not obscure, so lack of discussion of its presence in official materials has some indicative value.

Comment: Another way to check whether something is mentioned in 5e published material is to use D&D Beyond's search (and maybe filter results to compendium entries) - if it's in a book, it would show up there.

Answer (score 1):

The amulet of which you speak has never been gleaned into Dungeons and Dragons by TSR or WoTC.  Not only because the presence of a legal issue is difficult to discern, but because it would anger the gods...  No one would be so foolish!

That being said, although it is not your main concern, I can offer you a template on the properties of the Amulet of Yendor when considering how to implement it into Dungeons and Dragons.  Keep in mind it has always been a strange burden and privilege to carry or bear the Amulet of Yendor.

DnD stat and the justification for it:

When carrying the Amulet you know the terrain and position of objects and creatures within 30' but you do not know their quality or type.  i.e. you sense a bottle, but do not gain knowledge of the contents or sense a creature but do not sense its specie.  In NetHack(and other roguelikes) you have clairvoyance in a 19x11 region centered on you, the average is 30' radius approximately.

You cannot place the Amulet of Yendor in any container.  The Amulet of Yendor is stubborn and demands the dignity of being worn because it has power beyond mortal comprehension.

There are forgeries in existence, but even for the Amulet of Yendor these are exceptionally rare for the Amulet of Yendor is elusive, unique, and mysterious even to the most ancient of beings.

The Amulet of Yendor bestows a kind of detect magic for gates and portals to whomever wears it because it gets warmer in the vicinity of magical portals: 60' warm, 40' very warm, 15' hot.

The Amulet of Yendor increases metabolism and requires anyone carrying it consume twice as much food; therefore, regular rations would be counted as half-rations for the purpose of exhaustion in 5e.

High ranking ancient creatures of power such as demon lords, ancient dragons, and the like can sense the presence of the Amulet of Yendor and cannot be surprised by one who enters their domain.  They will not recognize exactly what it is; however, they will desire to possess it and their deity may inform them as they desire for it as well.

You must cast spells using the next higher spell slot.  Cantrips require a level 1 spell slot.  In NetHack there was an increase in spell cost.

Teleportation on the current plane of existence by spell fails 33% of the time.  Teleportation by spell to other planes is impossible for the possessor, except by a wish spell.  You may walk through a magical portal created by another or use Well of Many Worlds.  Not a bad way to nullify Banishment.

Attempting to leave the outer plane of Gehenna with the amulet has a 75% of success, unless using a wish spell.  Using a portal has a chance to teleport you to a random location within 5 miles of the portal.

Offering the Amulet of Yendor on the 'high alter' of your god in the astral plane grants you true immortality and great favor with your patron deity.

Because you are likely to be pursued by beings and things wherever you go once found out and because the Amulet of Yendor is such a great burden, it is ill advised to bestow this quest on anyone who does not have loyal friends to help whom are of sufficient level.

The rest of the Amulet of Yendor's properties from roguelike games do not translate to DnD or are superfluous in the context of DnD.